# What does the word "scalability" mean in terms of Big O?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algorithms, asymptotics, computational-complexity

I've encountered a lot of sources claiming that:

> Benchmarks estimate runtime, Big O estimates scalability.

They explained the meaning of "scalability" as follows:

> Scalability tells you how your algorithm runtime scales. Meaning, how the computation time grows when you increase the input size. For $O\left(n\right)$ you double the size of the input, and you double the computation time. For $O\left(n^2\right)$ you double the size of the input, and you quadruple the computation time and so on.

Meaning, if your algorithm takes $f(n)$ steps in the worst case and $f \in O\left(n^2\right)$, then the ratio $\frac{f(2n)}{f(n)}$ is equal to $4$ for large enough values of $n$ (you double the input size, and you quadruple the computation time).

And it made so much sense. But recently I've been shown a counterexample proving that the above statement is just wrong. Consider the function $f\left(n\right) = n^2\left(\cos (n) + 2\right)$. We can see that $f \in O\left(n^2\right)$. Moreover, for those of you who want to notice that by $O\left(n^2\right)$ people usually mean $\Theta\left(n^2\right)$ we can easily observe that $f \in \Theta\left(n^2\right)$ as well:

[image]

But $f$ doesn't scale like $n^2$ in the sense that we can't claim that $\frac{f(2n)}{f(n)}$ is equal to $4$ (even approximately) for any (even large) values of n. I mean if we know that $f \in O\left(n^2\right)$ and if we double its input size, we can't just quadruple the computation time, because it's wrong.

I made a plot of $\frac{f(2n)}{f(n)}$ for you to visualise it:

[image]

It doesn't look like this ratio is tending towards 4.

**So, my questions are:**

1. Why do people explain the meaning of "scalability" like that? Is there a reason for that or are they technically wrong?
2. What does this word "scalability" mean, then? What exactly does Big O estimate, then (if not "scalability")?

In general, I'm looking for pure mathematical explanation of that. But don't make it too difficult, please: I'm still learning a single variable calculus. Thank you all in advance!

Comment: There is an issue in that the limits don't technically exist. It is clear that $f$ is $\Theta(n^2)$ by the boundedness idea, but the limit definition notes that while the ratio of the functions definitely is finite and non-zero, the cosine limit is undefined at infinity (oscillation). I'm unsure here, but there may even be grounds to say that $f$ is not $O(n^2)$ at all by this token.

Comment: @FShrike, Thank you for the comment. But $f \in O\left(n^2\right)$ by the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) of Big O.

Comment: The scalability idea is confounded by oscillation, but there is no immediate conclusion of scalability from the limit definitions (although I now recall the limit definitions use limit suprema and infima to get around the idea that the regular limits don’t exist, so I take back some of what I said in the previous comment)

Comment: 1. Examples like this where $f \in \Theta(g)$ but $f/g$ is oscillatory as $n \to \infty$ are not common in actual practice. Offhand the only thing that comes to mind with this behavior is the FFT, and even that has a fixed scaling if you work along powers of 2 only. 2. Scalability still expresses the growth rate of the function in a rough way, how much bigger does it get when you increase the input by a bunch. Big Theta still gives you this rough description. But you are right that just knowing, say, $f \in \Theta(n^2)$ doesn't tell you that $f(2n)/f(n)$ will tend towards $4$.

Comment: In the context of complexity theory in particular people usually care about either worst cases or typical cases. Worst cases in your situation would mean "compare two problems where $n$ is near a multiple of $2\pi$"; typical cases would mean "compare two problems where $n$ is near an odd multiple of $\pi/2$".

Comment: @Ian, Thank you for the comment! In the last comment, you claim that $n^2\left(cos(n) + 2\right)$ can't be the worst case, because $3n^2$ is even worse?

Comment: I mean if the actual runtime is $n^2(\cos(n)+2)$ then the worst case for $n$ in one interval of length $2\pi$ is in going to be when $n$ is a multiple of $2\pi$ and in that case you have $3n^2$.

Comment: @Ian, But as I understand, there is no actual runtime if you don't specify the case first (worst, average, best). From this point when you classified it as worst, you deduce the function $f(n)$ which represent a number of steps taken for the worst case input of length $n$. But how can you go even further and specify separate points of the form $2πk$ to represent the worst case behavior, if we already have the function $f$ that represents the worst case behavior?

Comment: I mean that $n$ is the actual input size and $f(n)$ the actual runtime, and $f(n)$ fluctuates because somehow numbers close to odd integer multiples of $\pi$ are much easier to handle than numbers close to even integer multiples of $\pi$ (an unusual situation itself). So the worst $n$'s of a given "order of magnitude" are those near $2\pi k$, so if you want to study the growth of the worst case then you look at $n=\mathrm{round}(2\pi k),k=1,2,\dots$ (i.e. $6,13,19$ etc.)

Comment: @Ian, But do you agree that when we consider function $f(n)$ that already means every input $n$ must be the worst? Because $f(n)$ is by its definition takes only the worst case inputs

Comment: No, I'm talking about the locally worst values of $n$ (which is usually not a thing to even consider, but it's a thing in your case).

Answer (score 6):

This (very nice) example is quite unusual - in practice functions $f(n)$ that actually come up and are $\Theta(n^2)$ typically satisfy $f(n)/n^2$ tends to some positive limit (rather than merely being bounded away from $0$ and $\infty$). So the simplified version of scalability - $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(2n)/f(n)$ - exists and is $4$.

However, even for your function, there's still a reasonable sense in which doubling $n$, on average, increases $f(n)$ by a factor of $4$. What can we mean by "on average"? Well, to take an average you need to double more than once. If you double twice to go from $f(n)$ to $f(4n)$ then the average scaling factor of the two doublings that makes sense is the geometric mean (because you're trying to approximate by geometric growth), i.e. $\sqrt{f(4n)/f(n)}$. Now this doesn't tend to a limit either, but $\sqrt[k]{f(2^kn)/f(n)}$, i.e. the (geometric) average scaling factor from $k$ doublings, does tend to a limit as $k\to\infty$, which is $4$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But doesn't it look like we just invented out of thin air a way to justify the original meaning of the word "scale"?

Comment: Also, why is the arithmetic mean worse in this case? It seems to me as much reasonable as the geometric mean is.

Comment: @mathgeek It's basically because if we scale by a factor $x$ and then scale by a factor $y$, then the overall scaling is $xy$ not $x+y$. The idea of taking an average is "what list of $k$ identical things would be most like this list of $k$ different things?" Here scaling by $k$ different factors should give the same overall result as scaling by the "average" factor $k$ times, and that works if as "average" means the geometric mean.

Comment: I couldn't expect an explanation better than this! Thank you! But I can hardly imagine people thinking about all these computations when they say things like the runtime grows “on the order of the square of the size of the input”. Would you clarify what such people think about (what they actually mean) while saying it and if it is even legitimate to say so about $f$, given $f \in O(n^2)$?

Comment: It's still correct, it just can fail at the level of the comparing two particular function values if $f$ is weird. And I really cannot stress enough how atypical your example is in real asymptotic analysis, especially in complexity theory.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I don't see why it's misleading. I'm specifically talking about OP's example, which (as OP specificially says) is an example of a function which is $\Theta(n^2)$ but appears not to scale as expected. If you only know a function is $O(n^2)$, then in the second paragraph you basically need to replace $\lim$ by $\limsup$ and $4$ by $\leq 4$.

Answer (score 2):

The Landau symbols do not care about the exact behaviour of functions. $f\in O(g)$ means that for large $x$ we have $f$ scales at most so bad as $g$ in the sense that $f$ is bounded by a multiple of $g$.

When people explain it the way you mentioned it they are oversimplifying it, probably assuming that the other side would else not understand what one is talking about.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But if you look at my first plot you will notice that $f$ scales worse than $n^2$ at interval $\left(10;\ 12\right)$ for example. Therefore, It doesn't "scale AT MOST so bad as $g$".

Comment: @mathgeek We consider limits as $n\to\infty$ in the standard definition, not as $n\to(10,12)$

Comment: I just gave an example so you can easily observe it from the plot. But I'm sure you can see that my statement holds for any $n$ (you can make it as large as you want).

Comment: @mathgeek That is one of the caveats with Landau notation. Scaling is a term we use for the argument getting large, but we do not specify *how* large that would be. Note that if $f$ is continuous and $g$ is continous and nowhere $0$ then on any closed interval we always find a $c$ with $f\leq cg$ on that interval (min/max of cont. functions on compact sets). And even then, the definition of the Landau symbols always specifies: For all $x>x_0$ for some arbitrary $x_0$. So basically we do not care about finite values.

Comment: You can think about this this way: If $f\in O(g)$ then the asymptotic $\limsup\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is finite. If $f\in\Theta(g)$ then also $0<\liminf \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$.

Comment: Yes, your last comment is the definition, but unfortunately it doesn't explain the meaning of the word "scale" and why does it make sense in light of my posted question.

Comment: Well, scaling is usually not used in pure mathematics, but rather in context of algorithms and such. And here scaling just means: If I increase the input, how does the required time change. For example, if you were to sort a list of size $n$ the best algorithms that work without big assumptions have an order of $n\log n$ comparisations.

So if I increase the size of my list the required effort increases slightly more than linearly, but less than quadratically. Of course there are multiple things you can consider: Best case? Worst case? Average case?

Comment: Okay, when you pointed out that "scaling is usually not used in pure mathematics, but rather in context of algorithms" it started to make sense. You gave an example of algorithm running in $O\left(\log n\right)$ time. Could you clarify what you mean by "increases quadratically"? Please, keep in mind the example of the wrong explanation of "increases quadratically" that I gave in my question.